# Creating a RDP icon on desktop with specific parameters

Tags: powershell, rdp, intune

Does anybody have a Powershell script that generates a RDP icon on the desktop of the user. I already have the code for the desktop icon creation. But the next thing I need is the RDP extension to be created with specific paramters (Single usage of monitor)

Thanks in advance!

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\RDP.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Remote Desktop Connection.lnk"
$lnk.Description = "RDP"
$lnk.Save()
```

Comment: Your current target is a shortcut that points to mstsc, this is the executable that created the remote desktop connections. Check `mstsc /?` and create a custom target with the required arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You did it almost correct. But better to set TargetPath to mstsc.exe directly.
Use `$lnk.Arguments` to set parameters like server name (/v), fullscreen (/f) and others.

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\RDP.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe"
$lnk.Description = "RDP"
$lnk.Arguments = "/v:server-1 /f"
$lnk.Save()
```

If you need some tweaks inside mstsc its better to use shared folder for all computers and place .rdp file with your config here. After that use `$lnk.TargetPath` to this .rdp file.

Comment: Could you give me an example with all parameters? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ghostky [Here is link to Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc). BTW if my answer was correct for you, please do not forget to mark it as solving, Thanks!